# CS0426 type name does not exist when calling Create function

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

This is what I have in my library

```
public class ClassA
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public static class FactoryClass
    {

        public static ClassA CreateClassA(int value)
        {
            return new ClassA() { Value = value };
        }
    }
```

and this is in my program

```
ClassA a = new FactoryClass.CreateClassA(5);
```

Visual Studios is giving me a CS0426 error, but under the class library it's counting the reference, can anyone explain what it is that's going on?

Answer (score 3):

Your factory is *static*, all you need to do is remove the `new`:

```
ClassA a = FactoryClass.CreateClassA(5);
```

When you call:

```
ClassA a = new FactoryClass.CreateClassA(5);
```

It's trying to find a nested class in `FactoryClass` and initialize it. Hence the error:

> CS0426    The type name 'CreateClassA' does not exist in the type
> 'Program.FactoryClass'

---

**Additional Resources**

[Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)